# Better Moment Inequalities

Tags: random-variable, moments, probability-inequalities

How do you determine if a moment inequality is better than another?

Say for example, compare the Chebyshev's inequality with this nameless inequality where P{|X|≥ Kσ} ≤ (μ<sub>4</sub>-σ<sup>4</sup>)/(μ<sub>4</sub>+K<sup>4</sup>σ<sup>4</sup>-2K<sup>2</sup>σ<sup>4</sup>).

I read in a book that Chebyshev is better if 1≤K<sup>2</sup><(μ<sub>4</sub>/σ<sup>4</sup>) and the other inequality is better if K<sup>2</sup>≥(μ<sub>4</sub>/σ<sup>4</sup>). How do you prove this mathematically??

I forgot to mention. X is an rv with E[X]=0, V[X]=σ<sup>2</sup> and E[X<sup>4</sup>]=μ<sub>4</sub>. And K is any positive real number.

Comment: Is there a type, $k=K$?

Comment: All K's are the same in all expressions and it should be a positive real number.

Comment: How can the expectation of $X$ be both zero and $\mu_4$? Please read over your question and make sure everything is correct.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice that. Using sub and sup confuses me.